# DataGridView : How to update a record to database after edit

Tags: datagridview, bindingsource

I am using a DataGridView connecting  to a database via BindingSource and DataSet.
I hope that when a user finishing editing a row and leaving the row, the program can update the current row to database.
Where can I place my update code? (in which class and which event?)

Answer (score 0):

You can add in OnRowUpdated/OnRowUpdating